# Little curiosity $\Re\Big(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln(x)}{1+e^{ix}}dx\Big)=-\frac{1}{8}$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, exponential-function, complex-integration, residue-calculus

Playing with the integral of the [Glaisher–Kinkelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant) constant with $x\ln(x)$ I have found a little curiosity :

$$\Re\Big(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln(x)}{1+e^{ix}}dx\Big)=-\frac{1}{8}$$

I have tried the residue theorem without success .I can't find the right track to apply this. Obviously I have tried to apply the [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) .Moreover the imaginary part looks more complicated that's why I think it's not easy to calculate this directly.I have tried also to differentiate under the integral but it doesn't looks good ...Maybe add a parameter in the exponent of the exponential function ?Maybe we have

$$\Re\Big(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln(x)}{1+e^{i\alpha x}}dx\Big)=-\frac{1}{8}$$

Where $0<\alpha\leq \pi$ a real number

How to solve it ? is it well-know ?

Any helps is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance !

### Update :

Since it's too easy I add the following question :

What's the value of the parameter $\alpha$ such that :

$$-\Im\Big(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln(x)}{1+e^{i\alpha x}}dx\Big)=\Re\Big(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln(x)}{1+e^{i\alpha x}}dx\Big)=-\frac{1}{8}$$

Thanks again!

Comment: Well, $\Re[1/(1+e^{ix})]=1/2$. And $\int_0^1 x\ln x\,dx=-1/4$ of course.

Comment: @metamorphy How does this solve the problem?

Comment: For information we have $2.93<\alpha<2.94$.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note,

$$Re\left(\frac1{1+e^{ix}}\right) = Re\left(\frac{e^{-\frac{ix}{2}}}{e^{\frac{ix}{2}} + e^{-\frac{ix}{2}}}\right)
= Re\left(\frac{\cos\frac x2-i \sin \frac x2}{2\cos\frac x2}\right)=\frac12 $$

Thus,

$$\Re\Big(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln(x)}{1+e^{ix}}dx\Big)
=\frac12 \int_{0}^{1}{x\ln(x)}dx
$$

Comment: Ok And with the parameter it is the same proof ?Thanks (+1)